# Android Development - How to maintain common code across several android platforms

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

We are working on an native android App targeted for various android devices -

- Android TV - Leanback launcher
- Android Tablet
- Amazon Fire TV
- Android TV - China made unbranded (uses custom launchers)

Interestingly all of these four platforms have slightly different requirements for graphics assets, and Android TV with Leanback launcher have specific intent filter requirements.

This is my first real android project. It doesn't seem to make sense of creating different projects just to package different assets in specific apks.

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What exactly are the differences in the "graphics assets"? With respect to the `<intent-filter>`, it should be safe to have that for all of your targets, even if it is will be ignored on three of them. Whether this is simply one project, one project with product flavors, or a collection of modules (e.g., one common library and four app modules) depends a lot on the details... so we need those details.

Comment: other than <intent-filter> - the size of app-icon is different. Android TV & Fire TV use rectangular launcher Icons 
FireTV - 1280x720
Android TV - 320x180
Android Tablet & Android TV (uncertified) - Various standard sizes - Square or round based on display density  - Android studio takes care of these sizes - but NOT the rectangular ones.

Comment: That sounds fairly minor. In that case, I recommend a single project with product flavors, one for each distinct target. Each flavor can have its own `ic_launcher` resources (or whatever you are calling them) that is tailored for its environment. The code and manifest would stay the same and reside in `src/main/`, with the custom resources in flavor-specific directories (e.g., `src/firetv/`, `src/androidtv/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make different projects, since you're using Android Studio make different 'flavors' of the project.  That way you can make the various modifications you need for each platform and then during your build you can select which flavor to build. Check it out at [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create different modules. We have a similar situation: various products that are more or less the same except for a set of resources. Our approach is to define a library module that contains all the common code and resources, then create platform-specific application modules that depend on the library module and contain platform-specific content. Sometimes, to enable everything to compile, we need to define stub resources that are then replaced by the real thing when the products are assembled by Android Studio.

You can also use product flavors to tailor the builds for various releases.